# VB.net Shared vs C# Static accessibility differences, why?

Tags: c#, vb.net

This may be a dumb question - but why are shared methods availible on types and instances in VB.net - am I wrong to assume they are the equivalent to C# static methods?

i.e

```
MyClass.MySharedMethod()

dim mc as new MyClass()
mc.MySharedMethod()
```

Why am I allowed to do this?  What possible advantage is there to this - all I can see this doing is confusing people when using intellisense.  I'm sure this has to do with some convention from classic VB6 by why bother bring this up to .NET - it just seems so broken to me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it's basically a hangover from VB6. Java lets you do this too, but most IDEs warn you these days I believe.

And yes, it's a really bad idea. The most obvious example of it being bad is Thread.Sleep:

```
Dim t as new Thread(...)
t.Sleep(1000)
```

Which thread is sleeping? The current one. Doh!

Comment: Well, VB6 had no shared subs/functions in classes. How can this be a hangover?

Comment: @Konrad: Ooh, interesting. I'd heard (a while ago) that it was a backwards compatibility thing. Odd if it's not...

Comment: @Jon,Konrad, it seems even Paul doesn't know why this was allowed.  If he doesn't know, the decision is likely lost in time for good.  http://panopticoncentral.net/archive/2003/08/07/172.aspx

Comment: It turns out this was put into Vb.Net for ease of use.  At least that's the concensus of the people remaining from the time this was designed.

Answer (score 2):

> This may be a dumb question - but why are shared methods availible on types and instances in VB.net - am I wrong to assume they are the equivalent to C# static methods?

They are the same. VB *will* warn if you try to use them on instances but it's not forbidden. This has probably got to do with dynamic typing and late binding. Imagine that you've got a late-bound object (`Object`) without knowing its exact type. How would you go about calling a static method of its class?

As far as I know, this wouldn't be possible in C# (without resorting to reflection). In VB with `Option Strict Off`, you could simply call it as an instance method of the object.

Comment: ok so why is it not forbidden then - they know its a bad idea if they warn you - so why bother?

Comment: @kingfrito_5005 The `Static` keyword exists in VB but is something completely different (it regulates lifetime of local variables, something which C# does not support). For the sake of what OP asked (`static` methods), `Shared` in VB is the equivalent of `static` in C#.